# Удачная отправка письма

Tags: php, javascript, отправка

Не могу понять , как сделать так , чтобы при удачной проверки формы (  required ) показывался alert с сообщением о том , что письмо удачно отправилось.

```
<div class="sovet section section_5">
    <div class="main_word_sovet_modal">Заполните форму и получите совет как сэкономить 2000 рублей</div>
         <form action="post.php" method="post" id="form" class="js-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="on" required >
                <input type="tel" placeholder="Телефон" name="phone" id="phone" autocomplete="on" required >
                <button class="button_sovet js-button vf-submit">
                    <div class="word">
                        Получить совет
                            </div> 
                </button> 
        </form>           
    </div> 
</div>
```

Так-же прилагаю Js скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js-button').click(function(){
        var title=$('.js-title').val();
        var name=$('.js-name').val();
        var phone=$('.js-phone').val();
        var email=$('.js-email').val();

        var email_send=$('.js-email-send').val();


        $.post(
            'post.php',
            {
                title:title,
                name:name,
                phone:phone,
                email:email,
                email_send:email_send,
            },
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// На сервер будет отправлен запрос страницы http://hostname/ajaxtest.php и указаны два параметра. 
// После получения ответа от сервера будет вызвана функция onAjaxSuccess, которая выведет 
// на экран сообщение с данными, присланными сервером.
$.post(
  "/ajaxtest.php",
  {
    param1: "param1",
    param2: 2
  },
  onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{
  // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
  alert(data);
}
```

так же можно использовать [AJAX](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) пример:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```